# What is this m sign in the flutter pubspec.yaml file?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

What is this m sign in the flutter pubspec.yaml file?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

That is your VS Code syncing up with the Git. Here `M` implies the code has been modified

A - Added (This is a new file that has been added to the repository)

M - Modified (An existing file has been changed)

D - Deleted (a file has been deleted)

U - Untracked (The file is new or has been changed but has not been added to the repository yet)

C - Conflict (There is a conflict in the file)

R - Renamed (The file has been renamed)

S - Submodule (In repository exists another subrepository)